# How to validate if record does not found or mis match than display error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

My code for live search is working perfectly but I am not able to display error when my record is not matched. Please help me. Thanks
Here is my jquery code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
      $('#searchName').keyup(function(){
       $('#result').html('');
       $('#state').val('');
       var searchField = $('#searchName').val();
       var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
       $.getJSON('result.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
         if (value.name.search(expression) != -1)
         {
          $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.city+'</span></li>');
         }
         else
         {
             $('#error').html('<p> Error </p>');
         }
        });   
       });
      });

      $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
       var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
       $('#searchName').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
       $("#result").html('');
      });
     });

My index.html file
    <form method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Lorem name">
    <button  class="search-icon"><img src="images/search-icon.svg" alt="submit"></button>
    </form>
<ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the value of click_text[0] ?